# Exception comes while migrating my spring based maven project from JBoss EAP 6 to tomcat 8.0

Tags: spring, tomcat, jboss, jta

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean 
property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/config/core-spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
```

What things I've done for set up?

I have created the jndi resource. Initially the dataSourceBean initialisation error was coming, I resolved it by creating that jndi resource. The application.properties has also been correctly mapped and it is loading the same props. Now the above error is coming.

Assumption:
 1. The same app.war is working fine on jboss instance on my system. My tomcat is also on the same system. Few other apps like microservices are running well on the same tomcat but my main app is not.
2. I tried to run a sql query from init method of one of the beans, so sql connection/jdbctemplate is also fine.
I think the root cause should be some default spring jar related/path expression related.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is only a servlet container unlike Jboss that is a full fledged Java EE stack implementation and is a application server. so you may need changes when migrating from tomcat to Jboss if you have used Java EE features like JMS, JTA and So on. in this case you should determine Transaction manager in order to let Tomcat know what kind of transaction manager it should use.

Comment: I found something in xml where transactionmanager bean was getting initialised, here the code is referring

<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

Comment: Found the solution... I am happy to share that I changed above to 

<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource">
   <ref bean="dSource" />
  </property>  
 </bean>

and it worked.

Comment: Now Can anybody tell me why, JtaTransactionM‌​anager did not work while DataSourceTrans‌​actionManager worked?